# How to execute command line in a python loop?

Tags: python, windows, loops, python-2.7, popen

I am trying to determine the best way to execute something in command line using python.  I have accomplished this with [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) on individual files.  However, I am trying to determine the best way to do this many time with numerous different files.  I am not sure if I should create a batch file and then execute that in command, or if I am simply missing something in my code.  Novice coder here so I apologize in advance.  The script below returns a returncode of 1 when I use a loop, but a 0 when not in a loop.  What is the best approach for the task at hand?

```
def check_output(command, console):
    if console == True:
        process = subprocess.Popen(command)
    else:
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    returncode = process.poll()
    return returncode, output, error

for file in fileList.split(";"):
    ...code to create command string...
    returncode, output, error = check_output(command, False)
    if returncode != 0:
        print("Process failed")
        sys.exit()
```

EDIT: An example command string looks like this:

C:\Path\to\executable.exe -i C:\path\to\input.ext -o C:\path\to\output.ext

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Run a bunch of commands and get their output into Python? Chain each command together? Run them in parallel?

Comment: Run them sequentially, file 1, file2,...  I have an executable that I would like to run on several files, one at a time.

Comment: Could we get an example of what the command strings look like as they're passed in to `check_output`? Apart from a typo in Popen (`stder`) I don't see any reason for it to be failing.

Comment: Use subprocess' built-in check_output method for error checking

Comment: @wils484, process.communicate() returns None for error.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) "If the return code was non-zero [subprocess.check_output] raises a CalledProcessError." Try `subprocess.check_output("exit 1", shell=True)`

Comment: @wils484, I tried check_output, which returned `CalledProcessError: Command '[command string here]' returned non-zero exit status 1`, the same as `returncode` and `error` in my code.  Not sure why I get the error, the executable appears to do what it is supposed to.

Comment: @Barbarossa this is how it is supposed to work. `check_output` raises an error if the shell command exits with code 1, and `exit 1` is simply a shell command to exit with code 1. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the commands module (only available before python 3)

```
>>> import commands
>>> commands.getstatusoutput('ls /bin/ls')
(0, '/bin/ls')
```

Your code might look like this

```
import commands

def runCommand( command ):
    ret,output = commands.getstatutoutput( command )
    if ret != 0:
        sys.stderr.writelines( "Error: "+output )
    return ret

for file in fileList.split(';'):
    commandStr = ""
    # Create command string
    if runCommand( commandStr ):
        print("Command '%s' failed" % commandStr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

You are not entirely clear about the problem you are trying to solve. If I had to guess why your command is failing in the loop, its probably the way you handle the console=False case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are merely running commands one after another, then it is probably easiest to cast aside Python and stick your commands into a bash script. I assume you merely want to check errors and abort if one of the commands fails.

```
#!/bin/bash

function abortOnError(){
    "$@"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "The command $1 failed with error code $?"
        exit 1
    fi
}

abortOnError ls /randomstringthatdoesnotexist
echo "Hello World" # This will never print, because we aborted
```

**Update**: OP updated his question with sample data that indicate he is on Windows.
You can get `bash` for Windows through [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or various other packages, but it may make more sense to use PowerShell if you are on Windows. Unfortunately, I do not have a Windows box, but there should be a similar mechanism for error checking.  Here is a [reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx) for PowerShell error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

```
from subprocess import call

for file_name in file_list:
    call_args = 'command ' + file_name
    call_args = call_args.split() # because call takes a list of strings 
    call(call_args)
```

It also will output 0 for success and 1 for failure.

Comment: This produces the same result as the `subprocess.Popen()` in my code.  The strange thing is that it appears the executable does what it is supposed to do, but still returns a `1`.  Is it possible I need to wait on the subprocess?

Comment: @Barbarossa If the subprocess finishes correctly, how does the process exit?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned.  I commented out the `if returncode != 0` section to see if it would run without verifying that the subprocess completed or not.  Everything seems to work if I do not worry about return codes, but I was under the assumption that a return code of 1 means there was an error.

Comment: @Barbarossa I would try printing the returncode, to see what is actually happening with it. I can't imagine that it has a defined state until the command finishes.

Answer (score 0):

What your code is trying to accomplish is to run a command on a file, and exit the script if there's an error. `subprocess.check_output` accomplishes this - if the subprocess exits with an error code it raises a Python error. Depending on whether you want to explicitly handle errors, your code would look something like this:

```
file in fileList.split(";"):
    ...code to create command string...
    subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

Which will execute the command and print the shell error message if there is one, or

```
file in fileList.split(";"):
    ...code to create command string...
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        ...handle errors...
        sys.exit(1)
```

Which will print the shell error code and exit, as in your script.